# How to open form from user control inside main form

Tags: c#, user-controls

In my c# program it contains `mainForm` and `user-control1` which has `buttons` , when I press a `user control1 button` I need it to open `branchForm` but inside `mainForm` while `IsMdiContainer is true` I tried many ways and solutions but not working.

In button in `mainForm` this code below works for me but I need it from `user control button`.

```
branchForm newMDIChild = new branchForm(); 
            newMDIChild.TopLevel = true;
            newMDIChild.MdiParent = this; 
            newMDIChild.Show();
```

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to open a form and make it an MDI child of the same form that the user control is on?

Comment: If that is the case, all controls have a `FindForm` method that returns the form they are on. You can call that in your user control and assign the result to the `MdiParent` of your new form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you code will be like this :

UserControl code
First you have to define the Parent

```
    public mainForm main
    {
        get
        {
            var parent = Parent;
            while (parent != null && (parent as mainForm) == null)
            {
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            return parent as mainForm;
        } 
    }
```

In Button Add this code

```
branchForm newMDIChild = new branchForm(); 
            newMDIChild.TopLevel = true;
            newMDIChild.MdiParent = main; 
            newMDIChild.Show();
```

Comment: @Code_null A UserControl has a `ParentForm` property, so it's as simple as `newMDIChild.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;`